# Getting specific range of characters from a string swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i would like to get specific characters from my string, like this for example

```
var str = "hey steve @steve123, you would love this!"

// Without doing this
var theCharactersIWantFromTheString = "@steve123"
```

How would i just retrieve the @steve123 from str

Comment: You'd better clarify your requirement. The range alway starts with `@`? Or some characters can proceed `@`? Then letters (1+ or 0+?) follow and then digits? Or letters and digits can appear in arbitrary order? Or some limited symbols can be mixed?

Comment: I only want the @symbol and albetical characters

Comment: You usually do not include digits in _alphabetical characters_. But your example has digits `123`. Please clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use regular expression `"\\B\\@\\w+"`.

```
let pattern = "\\B\\@\\w+"
let sentence = "hey steve @steve123, you would love this!"

if let range = sentence.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
    print(sentence.substring(with: range))  // "@steve123\n"
}
```